# Empty comment field has notice "enter at least undefined characters"

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

When I open a new comment field, but before I have entered anything, next to the Add Comment button it says "enter at least undefined characters". When entering something then deleting all of it, the same message appears. This occurred on the page [Can I POP a value from the stack, but put it nowhere in NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418781/can-i-pop-a-value-from-the-stack-but-put-it-nowhere-in-nasm-assembly) but seems to happen regardless which page I use.

This is on Mozilla Firefox 68.0.2 on Android 9. No userscripts I'm aware of. By next to I mean that below the comment field, on the left hand side there is the Add Comment button, and in the middle (to the right of the button) there is the status message indicating either what I reported or (eg now) "267 characters left".

Screenshot:

[image: Comment field that is empty, with the "enter at least undefined characters" status message showing.]

Comment: Okay, I repro-ed that on Chrome. It is the mobile view that is borked

Comment: @Catija: Done and done. I had to edit using the desktop version (Request Desktop Site option), the mobile editor doesn't seem to provide any way to upload images.

Comment: @rene happens to me on full web view too, Chrome on mobile device.

Comment: @ShadowTheDragonWizard super weird. Full site works for.

Comment: @rene so maybe it's a responsive design issue?

Comment: @ShadowTheDragonWizard well, I attached the debugger but as it happens from a closure over the delayedReaction function I kind of lost track where it orginates from. It is clear an object that expects min and max only got the value for max. Why that is only happening in mobile is unclear.

Comment: also reported on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389353/578411

Comment: Interestingly, the entire thing disappears when typing a single char (and says `599 chars left`). Comment length validation still works. Repro'd in FF on Android

Comment: Ooops I reported this as well in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334859/209901, I am trying to close as a dupe