# "enter at least *undefined* characters" when about to comment in the mobile site

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

When you want to leave a comment in the full site, initially there is the text:

> enter at least 15 characters
>
> [image]

However, in the mobile version of the site, it shows:

> enter at least **undefined** characters

See an image:

> [image]

Comment: Yep also in MSOes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4370/83